# Ubuntu Server 16.04 Nvidia GT218-ION Driver

Tags: nvidia, xinit

I am running Ubuntu Server 16.04 Xenial on my mini itx board with a Nvidia GT218-ION videocard.
I installed kodi and xinit but I seem to mis the correct Nvidia drivers, nvidia-304 (current) dont work with the latest version of xinit as it seems.

Nouveau drivers gives me:
List of video drivers:
    nouveau
    modesetting
No devices to configure.  Configuration failed.
(EE) Server terminated with error (2). Closing log file.

The nvidia-367 seems to work but also installs gnome which i dont want.

I did install the nvidia driver from their website now but i got this error:
[  2922.845] (II) LoadModule: "nvidia"
[  2922.846] (WW) Warning, couldn't open module nvidia
[  2922.846] (II) UnloadModule: "nvidia"
[  2922.846] (II) Unloading nvidia
[  2922.846] (EE) Failed to load module "nvidia" (module does not exist, 0)

when i try to install nvidia-340 through the apt repo i get this: pastebin.com/YaJhq4m5 as you can see it wants to install gnome and unity packages

Comment: *The nvidia-367 seems to work but also installs gnome* ????? No, installing a graphics drivers does not install a desktop environment. Besides, 304 is old, not current, and doesn't support ION. According to Nvidia you need 340 (and only this version): http://www.nvidia.com/download/driverResults.aspx/107868/en-us

Comment: Yes I installed the 340 driver from the nvidia website but I get this error now:
[  2922.845] (II) LoadModule: "nvidia"
[  2922.846] (WW) Warning, couldn't open module nvidia
[  2922.846] (II) UnloadModule: "nvidia"
[  2922.846] (II) Unloading nvidia
[  2922.846] (EE) Failed to load module "nvidia" (module does not exist, 0)

Comment: You need to remove all previous versions before installing a new one: `sudo apt purge nvidia`. Reboot. Then you should be able to install the drivers already in the official repos: `sudo apt install nvidia-340`.

Comment: when i try to install nvidia-340 through the apt repo i get this: http://pastebin.com/YaJhq4m5 as you can see it wants to install gnome

Comment: Please edit and add all that information to your question, not just as a comment.

Comment: done i thougt this was kind of a side track sorry for that

Comment: any idea why it tries to install gnome?

Answer (score 0):

I installed the nvidia-340 from the repository and after that removed unity-greeting.

after a apt-get autoremove also all the other gui stuff got removed

Its working for now but it stays weird that a graphics driver installs unity and gnome stuff